# Microsoft Graph InTune Beta API's - Unable to create managed device

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am attempting to use Intune API to create a managedDevice, documented here
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_devicefe_windowsmanageddevice_create

I get a 400 bad request response that appears to say this endpoint either does not exist or is not responding correctly

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": "No method match route template",
    "message": "No OData route exists that match template ~/entityset with http verb POST for request /DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/managedDevices.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "4b7a8605-3853-44d2-826c-d330e36112c2",
      "date": "2017-11-03T08:10:02"
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
I use Beta endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/managedDevices/

Comment: Are you hitting the beta endpoint (`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta`)?

Comment: Yes, I use https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/managedDevices/ endpoint

Comment: Hmm, then that is quite odd. From the looks of the error, it might be generated by the Intune API, which the Graph API is calling for you..

Answer (score 0):

The Intune graph API is not designed to create managedDevice. A managedDevice will be created when a device is enrolled into Intune. Then with Intune graph API, we can list the devices, check specific device details or issue actions for a device.